# React Native IOS White Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

React native splash screen is waiting, then white screen.

It works fine on IOS simulator and android but not on physical ios device

then i get this error: This method must not be called before the JS thread is created

[image]"react-native": "0.61.5",
node v15.0.1

edit:I understand it must be on the same network, but I am connecting to an external device via wifi and receiving data. How can we eliminate the need to connect to the same network?

Comment: did you try to connect via `localhost` instead of the ip address of your machine?

Comment: No,  how i try, i dont know

Answer (score 0):

If anybody come looking for a solution, make sure you have NOT remove

```
        <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        </dict>
```

You ONLY want to remove this when building for release.